# Powershell - add variables inside a json string

Tags: powershell

I have the following json code in my powershell script.
I set the $variable to 1111111111

```
$jsonfile = '{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": {"Effect": "Allow","Action": "sts:AssumeRole","Resource": "arn:aws:iam::$variable:role/xxxxxx"}}'
```

The output gives ....arn:aws:iam::**$variable**:role/xxxxxx..... instead of ....arn:aws:iam::**1111111111**:role/xxxxxx

The problem is that I must use the single quote for the json string otherwise I will get an error. If I use single quote I wont be able to put the variables inside the string. How do I workaround this problem?

Answer (score 10):

There are various ways to solve your problem, but perhaps the easiest approach is to use **PowerShell's string interpolation**:

- use a [*double-quoted* (expandable) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) overall to enable interpolation of embedded variable references and subexpressions (`$(...)`).
- escape embedded `"` chars. as `` `" `` (using backticks)
- disambiguate variable references by enclosing the variable name in `{...}`.

Simplified example:

```bash
$variable='111'
# -> verbatim:  {"Version": "arn:aws:iam::111:role/xxxxxx"}
"{`"Version`": `"arn:aws:iam::${variable}:role/xxxxxx`"}"
```

Note that enclosing variable names in `{...}` in interpolated strings is only necessary if the following char. could be misinterpreted as part of the variable name.
A `:` following the variable name - as is the case here - is such a case, because PS variables can have a scope specifier preceding the variable name that is separated from the variable name with `:`, such as in `$env:USERNAME`.

---

[DAXaholic's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38387700/45375) shows an alternative based on **PowerShell's  [`-f` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)**, which is essentially the same as the **.NET framework's [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method**; as such:

- it introduces additional complexity, such as needing to know what *its* escaping rules are (`{` chars. must be escape as `{{`, and how to format its arguments specified on the RHS of `-r` (`{0}` refers to the 1st RHS argument, ...)
- on the flip side, `-f` offers many sophisticated formatting options.

Also, consider use of the `Convert*-Json` cmdlets his answer demonstrates: even though they're less performant, they ultimately make manipulation of JSON much easier and more robust.

---

**Alternatives in the realm of native PowerShell code**:

- **String concatenation** with the binary **`+`** operator:

```bash
'{"Version": "arn:aws:iam::' + $variable + ':role/xxxxxx"}}'
```

- **String templating** with `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()`:

```bash
$variable='111'    
$tmpl = '{"Version": "arn:aws:iam::${variable}:role/xxxxxx"}}' # string template *literal*
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($tmpl) # performs on-demand interpolation
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be

```
$jsonfile = '{{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": {{"Effect": "Allow","Action": "sts:AssumeRole","Resource": "arn:aws:iam::{0}:role/xxxxxx"}}}}' -f $variable
```

So you have to escape the braces with another brace but in your case you have fewer braces than quotes so it is "less obfuscation" :)

In your case, maybe the simplest solution is just concatenating the strings together instead of using string formatting / interpolation.

In addition you could also go the way with the JSON cmdlets:

```
$jsonfile | 
    ConvertFrom-Json | 
    % { $_.Statement.Resource = "arn:aws:iam::${variable}:role/xxxxxx"; $_ } | 
    ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: That's a viable solution, but now you're dealing with _another_ language's escaping and formatting rules (PowerShell's binary `-f` operator is essentially the .NET framework's [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method, which adds complexity.

Comment: Well yeah but IMHO it is more readable then escaping all the other characters and usually code is more often read than rewritten. Anyway, I wouldn't see both solutions (escaping " or {})  as perfect and therefore would go with simple concat in this case as there is no benefit of using string interpolation or formatting just for the sake of being used.

Comment: I get that escaping chars. can be noisy and distracting, but if you're going to escape, you may as well use the native rules of the language at hand. Point taken about simple string concatenation. I've tried to summarize all options in my answer; let me know if I've missed anything.

Comment: Yeah true, I think if you came from using ", recognized it didn't work then move to ' and it still not works and then should start replacing { with {{ it may become silly :) Good summary, give you an up - I just added another possible solution with the JSON cmdlets which is more code but with no need for escaping at all

Comment: Thanks; similarly, pointing to the `Convert*-Json` cmdlets as a (costly in terms of performance, but vastly superior in terms of convenience and robustness) alternative  is worth a ++ too.

Comment: I am getting Input `Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 'Here-string'. It is declared just like a regular string except it has an @ on each end. For example:

```
$jsonfile = @"
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
      "Effect": "Allow", 
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::$variable:role/xxxxxx"}
  }
"@
```

However, in this particular example, the `:role` part confuses Powershell a bit. So you need to escape the colon like `` $variable`:role ``  or wrap the variable like `$($variable):role` or `${variable}:role`.